# Constructing a trapping region in a 2D dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

> Consider a system of the form $$\frac{d}{dt}x \enspace = \enspace 2-\left(b+1\right)x + ax^2y$$ $$\frac{d}{dt}y\enspace=\enspace bx-ax^2y$$

This is the context of some homework I have. I've already proven that one fixed point exists (namely $\left(x^*,y^*\right)=\left(2,\frac{b}{2a}\right)$).

The remainder of the question assumes $a=b=1$. I'm asked to sketch the nullclines and construct a trapping region for the flow. I'm basing my method off of how Strogatz approaches the Selkov model of glycolysis in his textbook. A phase portrait of that model can be found on the 7th slide [here](https://www.imsc.res.in/~sitabhra/teaching/sb15/Presentation_20.pdf).

Constructing the trapping region for my system is almost the same process as how Strogatz does it for glycolysis, but in my case the nullcline associated with $\dot{y}=0$ is asymptotic with the y-axis, whereas Strogatz has a handy y-intercept to work with.

The trapping region should look something like the thing on page 3 [here](https://staff.ul.ie/burkem/Teaching/TRs%20for%20PBT.pdf). The difference is that I'm not sure where the upper end of the diagonal line stops and the horizontal line starts.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I failed to understand what exactly is your question.